# Expand that Australian state

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

There are 8 Australian states and territories, each with a 2 or 3 letter abbreviation:

- ACT: Australian Capital Territory
- NSW: New South Wales
- NT: Northern Territory
- QLD: Queensland
- SA: South Australia
- TAS: Tasmania
- VIC: Victoria
- WA: Western Australia

> Your task is to write a function/program which takes a valid Australian state abbreviation in upper case, and returns the correct full name (case-sensitive as above).

No extra whitespace permitted, other than a single trailing newline where this is an unavoidable side-effect of every program in that language.

For example:

`f("TAS") => "Tasmania"`

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules (shortest code in bytes wins!) and loopholes apply.

Comment: I think we need to create the [[tag:state-abbreviation]] tag at this point.

Comment: What about "New South (Far) Wales"? (For those who don't realize, it's "NSFW")

Comment: while I was playing around with a solution, NSW was expanding to "New South Western ales" which I quite liked :)

Comment: Weird. I created the tag and added it, but someone removed it again.

Comment: state-abbreviation might be too specific. maybe make the tag something about abbreviations/acronyms?

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>135</s> 121 bytes

*13 bytes golfed thanks to @Neil by using clever space insertion tactics, which inspired one more byte being golfed*

```
AS
asmania
^W
Western 
NT
NorthernT
T$
 Territory
A
Australia
aC
an Capital
IC
ictoria
LD
ueensland
SW
ew SWales
S
South
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY5LCgIxEET3dYosFLxGiCCCDEiC2YmNNkwgZqTTQTx97GVRn1fCWhrN/eH0mD6C@ptaIdwzMndlaQ5LwrKJriYS0g4usUjRTX7w8KOrULUKBVBzgT5FqeIcUJ6WMeNyxGBuvVJ7IWbw18VMlTsi4jZ0dXP6YBDzjHW1fPRI9uZmK9n/AQ)

Note the trailing spaces on the fourth and the last lines.

Comment: If you replace `AS` with `asmania` first, then you can replace all the remaining `A`s with `Australia`.

Comment: You can also get creative with your space insertion, something like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY5NCkIxDIT3c4ouFLxGqCCCCNJitwYNvELtkzQP8fQ1y2F@vlGx2nnuD6fHpAQeb@6VUQhFhon2QLhmXFe1xVVG3iFkUa226g8E2oYpN@9wBPcQ@VONG84R9ekZNy5HbCJ9NO4vpAL5hlS4yUBCWjdbwpwUHeKes26eT4Tsd@6@UugP "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: (But for that, `\B[A-Z]` would have saved you two bytes.)

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the tips, I used your suggestions to golf one more byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 56 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OS%15ị“ÞÑṿ“ıÐṁṾṗ“¡ʋẹḢ⁾ḅ“¢T¡ż¶““msẒw²ẉṪP“ØÑĊ“©$Ḅ3ẊḳƓ“ÇH°»
```

A monadic link taking and returning lists of characters.

See all cases at **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/WNXQ9OHu7kcNcw7POzzx4c79QNaRjYcnPNzZ@HDnvoc7pwP5hxae6n64a@fDHYseNe57uKMVJLQo5NDCo3sObQOygSi3@OGuSeWHNj3c1flw56oAkGkzDk880gVSuVLl4Y4W44e7uh7u2HxsMkiq3ePQhkO7/x9uf9S0JvL//2glR@cQJR0lv@BwEAliBvq4AMlgRyAR4hgMJMM8nYFkuKNSLAA)**

*Note:* Reusing the words "Australia" and "Territory" does not help reduce the byte count.

#### How?

Taking the sum of the ordinals of the eight state abbreviations modulo 15 gives 8 unique values. Taking the results of those modulo 9 maintains uniqueness.

```
OS%15ị“ ... » - Main link: list of characters a
O             - cast to ordinals
 S            - sum
  %15         - modulo 15
      “ ... » - list of compressed strings:
              -   "Victoria"
              -   "Western Australia"
              -   "Northern Territory"
              -   "South Australia"
              -   ""
              -   "Australian Capital Territory"
              -   "Tasmania"
              -   "New South Wales"
              -   "Queensland"
     ị        - index into (1-indexed and modular - hence the single empty entry)
```

Comment: Sad that reusing Australia and Territory doesn't help :/

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>193</s> 192 bytes

```
f"NSW"="New South Wales"
f"QLD"="Queensland"
f"ACT"=a++"n Capital"++t
f"VIC"="Victoria"
f"TAS"="Tasmania"
f"SA"="South "++a
f"NT"="Northern"++t
f"WA"="Western "++a
a="Australia"
t=" Territory"
```

Somewhat naive solution, but I wanted to go for a fairly simple challange for my first. I'm not even sure if better is possible in Haskell.

Saved a byte by moving the space into t

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 177 bytes

Obvious solution: (199 bytes)

```
<|"ACT"->"Australian Capital Territory","NSW"->"New South Wales","NT"->"Northern Territory","QLD"->"Queensland","SA"->"South Australia","TAS"->"Tasmania","VIC"->"Victoria","WA"->"Western Australia"|>
```

Improved solution: (182 bytes, only runnable on my Wolfram Mathematica 10.2 computer)

```
{,"Northern Territory","Queensland",,,,,"Australian Capital Territory","New South Wales",,,"Tasmania",,,"Western Australia","Victoria",,,,,,,,,,,,"South Australia"}[[Hash@#~Mod~29]]&
```

Best solution:

```
{,"Northern Territory","Queensland",a="Australia",,,,a<>"n Capital Territory","New South Wales",,,"Tasmania",,,"Western "<>a,"Victoria",,,,,,,,,,,,"South "<>a}[[Hash@#~Mod~29]]&
```

Unfortunately repeat `" Territory"` can save only 0 bytes.

It seems that the default Hash function of Mathematica change over versions. But adding a method will make code longer.
Using the default Hash function of Mathematica sandbox now can make code shorter by about 9 bytes.

### Mathematica (sandbox - now - version 11), 168 bytes

```
{a="Australia","Western "<>a,,,,"South "<>a,,a<>"n Capital Territory",,,,"Tasmania","Northern Territory",,,,"New South Wales","Victoria","Queensland"}[[Hash@#~Mod~20]]&
```

Comment: Damn, only 21 bytes better than trivial answer.

Comment: Wait, so Mathematica has no builtin for this?

Comment: @Neil I should have thought about that first.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 181 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Jonathan Allan*

```
lambda a,s='Australia',t=' Territory':[s+'n Capital'+t,'New South Wales','Northern'+t,'Queensland','South '+s,'Tasmania','Victoria','Western '+s]['ACNSNTQLSATAVIWA'.index(a[:2])//2]
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/I5wG/1)

Comment: `t=' Territory'` should save a byte I think.

Answer (score 2):

## Sed, <s>167</s> 157 bytes

```sed
s/T$/ Territory/
s/N /Northern /
s/AS/asmania/
s/IC/ictoria/
s/LD/ueensland/
s/W$/Wales/
s/A/Australia/
s/C/n Capital/
s/NS/New S/
s/^W/Western /
s/S/South /
```

Comment: I did originally defer `ern `, but that cost more than it saved for just two usages.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>148</strike> 143 bytes

```
<?=strtr(["0n Capital 3",Victoria,Queensland,West20,10,Tasmania,North23,"New 1 Wales"][md5(hj.$argn)%8],[Australia,"South ","ern ",Territory]);
```

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%c3%b6rg-h%c3%bclsermann).

Answer (score 0):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/adf7b20bc97fa0d1597d5fd5eb2b4ab5), 289 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `String` `s` The abbreviation of the state.
- **Output** `String` The expanded state name

---

#### Golfed

```cs
(string s)=>{return new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>(){{"ACT","Australian Capital Territory"},{"NSW","New South Wales"},{"NT","Northern Territory"},{"QLD","Queensland"},{"SA","South Australia"},{"TAS","Tasmania"},{"VIC","Victoria"},{"WA","Western Australia"}}[s];};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
( string s ) => {
    return new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "ACT", "Australian Capital Territory" },
        { "NSW", "New South Wales" },
        { "QLD", "Queensland" },
        { "TAS", "Tasmania" },
        { "VIC", "Victoria" },
        { "NT", "Northern Territory" },
        { "SA", "South Australia" },
        { "WA", "Western Australia" }
    }[ s ];
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Takes a state name abbreviated 
( string s ) => {
    
    // Creates a dictionary with the state name abbreviated and the full state name and returns the one that match
    return new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "ACT", "Australian Capital Territory" },
        { "NSW", "New South Wales" },
        { "QLD", "Queensland" },
        { "TAS", "Tasmania" },
        { "VIC", "Victoria" },
        { "NT", "Northern Territory" },
        { "SA", "South Australia" },
        { "WA", "Western Australia" }
    }[ s ];
};
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Namespace {
   class Program {
      static void Main( String[] args ) {
         Func<String, String> f = ( string s ) => {
             return new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>() {
                 { "ACT", "Australian Capital Territory" },
                 { "NSW", "New South Wales" },
                 { "QLD", "Queensland" },
                 { "TAS", "Tasmania" },
                 { "VIC", "Victoria" },
                 { "NT", "Northern Territory" },
                 { "SA", "South Australia" },
                 { "WA", "Western Australia" }
             }[ s ];
         };
         
         List<String>
             testCases = new List<String>() {
                 "ACT",
                 "NSW",
                 "QLD",
                 "TAS",
                 "VIC",
                 "NT",
                 "SA",
                 "WA",
             };
         
         foreach( String testCase in testCases ) {
             Console.WriteLine( $"Input: {testCase}\nOutput: {f( testCase )}\n");
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `289 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Comment: `(string s)` can just be `s`, You can use an implicit return: `s=>new System....` and you can remove the trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rexx (Regina)](http://www.rexx.org/), <s>148</s> 147 bytes

```
a=Australia
t=Territory
s=South
ac=a'n' Capital t
ns=New s Wales
nt=Northern t
qs=Queensland
sa=s a
ta=Tasmania
vi=Victoria
wa=Western a
arg x 3
say value(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xDsIwEAR7v8JdQHT0V0T0kVAiUq/CiVgyDtxdEuf1xnQrrWZGOOdSQO2qJogBzmhgkWCLHE6pX1abHSZC0zX@hk8wRG8uKXW8e/UjIqtLRt0iNrOken6V7itz0oj0dApSX72gAfpGqo0t0CNMNVH3DhpZ7U/CQV4@@8u1QoffEFc@5XMpZWj78gM)

Comment: Seems to output in uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 167 bytes

```
s=>({A:`${A='Australia'}n Capital ${T='Territory'}`,N:s[2]?'New South Wales':'Northern '+T,T:'Tasmania',Q:'Queensland',S:'South '+A,V:'Victoria',W:'Western '+A}[s[0]])
```

```js
f=
s=>({A:`${A='Australia'}n Capital ${T='Territory'}`,N:s[2]?'New South Wales':'Northern '+T,T:'Tasmania',Q:'Queensland',S:'South '+A,V:'Victoria',W:'Western '+A}[s[0]])

console.log('ACT NSW NT QLD SA TAS VIC WA'.split(' ').map(f))
```